# importing npm/buffer package in Typescript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, buffer

I want to use this NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer

I don't know how to write this line of code in typescript:

```
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer
```

please give me the exact code.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
const encoded_key = Buffer.from(`${process.env.Key:process.env.Secret}`).toString('base64');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).